# "In the cases" vs. "in cases"

Tags: definite-article

Considering the following sentence I made:

> **In cases** where the scope of a context is specified using “Preceding”, the root of the document is counted as the beginning of the context and the anchor node marks the end of it.

Should it be "in the cases"? Is there any difference?

When to use "the", specially for plural names? As they may seem to be general!?

Comment: You might change your mind if you searched for `"in the case" flabby writing`. This is the fourth link Google gave me: http://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/340600179/m/9281060114.

Answer (score 2):

Your question relates to when to use the zero article[1], so you might try reading on when its use is appropriate. In general, it is with plural or mass nouns that you can drop the article. Here, you have an in-between situation where either would be appropriate.

"In the cases" makes it slightly more concrete, with a slight implication there are only a few "cases", or especially where those "cases" are specifically known to the reader.

If the cases are numerous and not specifically known, then the zero article emphasizes that. However, as Damkerng has pointed out, in that case you perhaps might as well just drop "In cases" entirely, since it is no longer serving any function. This is a matter of style (a detailed point of style, I would say, it did not occur to me until reading the linked post), and you can optionally leave the "In cases" on there if you like it.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-marking_in_English#Zero_article